# How can we preserve the value of a global variable in protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am running Selenium Grid for Protractor test executions. I need to preserve certain values after each spec runs but global variables aren't persisting their old values. 
Is there a way I can declare some variable and that can be accessible across all test case executions without losing it's value. I already tried Params, Browser nothing worked. They don't have any value over when next test file get executed:
1. onPrepare
2. beforeEach
Note: Each test case is in different file.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Set it in your config file under the `onPrepare()` function.  I use it just for Page Objects and other random stuff, don't see why it wouldn't work for regular variables. Example:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    global.Util = require('../util.js');
    global.Index = require('../page-objects/index.po.js');
};
```

This also works if you simply want to declare a variable in the config, and then assign a value from within a spec. Call that variable in another spec and it retains the value assigned.